# How to preserve const-ness of typedef'd types

Tags: c++

Every once in a while I get hung up by this and no one has really been able to give a satisfying answer.

In a (admittedly contrived) example like this...

```
typedef std::string _str;
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(const _str &s) : m_str(s) { }
private:
    const _str &m_str;
}
```

... Things work pretty much as expected. The member `m_str` can only be assigned in the constructor initializer list and cannot be reassigned later on, and non-const iterators are unavailable. Okay, then. But if we do this instead...

```
typedef std::string _str;
typedef std::string &_strref;
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(const _strref s) : m_str(s) { }
    void test() { m_str.append(std::string("why am I not const?")); }
private:
    const _strref m_str;
}
```

... The const gets dropped. Non-cost methods may be called on `m_str` and it may be reassigned, which is misleading considering it has `const` written next to it.

- Can the second example be corrected to maintain const-ness?
- Where/why does the c++ spec indicate that this is correct behavior?
- What do best practices have to say on the matter?

Comment: What about `typedef const std::string &_strcref;`?

Comment: As a note: I wouldn't typedef references and pointers. There is no real benefit and it hides information. You save typing one chracter and in you example you even type more.

Comment: See here for similar post - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8504502/2065121

Answer (score 7):

The problem is what we understand by saying "const reference". It's a bit confusing. It's not the reference which should be const, but the referenced object:

```
const std::string &
```

should be read as "reference to a const string" (but not "const reference to a string").

You defined a type-alias for a string reference. You then instantiated a const reference to such. But references are always const, so your `const` is ignored. *The string* referenced by this reference is **not** const.

It's more or less similar to this problem: A pointer to a const-string makes sure you don't modify the string behind the pointer. A const pointer to a non-const-string makes sure you don't re-seat the pointer (which is not possible with references, so when we say "const reference" we always mean the first case!)

So to put things in a nutshell: When type-aliasing a reference you have to care about const-ness already, not later (the same holds for pointers, by the way). So you need another typedef for a reference to a const string, like this:

```
typedef const std::string &_strcref;
```

Answer (score 4):

The const gets "dropped" because you don't have a reference to a const string, you have a const-reference to a non-const string, and a const-reference is meaningless, references can never be re-bound anyway, they're bound to a single object once and stay that way.

i.e. your

```
const _strref m_str;
```

is not

```
const string& m_str;
```

but rather

```
string& const m_str;
```

and that type doesn't make sense, so the `const` gets dropped and it's just

```
string& m_str;
```

Put another way, you can't "insert" the `const` "inside" the typedef. The typedef is `string&`, a reference to a `string`, you can't change it to be a reference to a different type (a `const string`) by putting `const` before it ... that can't change the type of object the reference refers to.

The best solution, as pointed out by one of the comments, is don't use typedefs for references, it gains you nothing. If you use `_str&` instead of `_strref` then you can add `const` without problems, as either `const _str&` or `_str const&`

Answer (score 4):

The core of the issue is that a typedef introduced something like "parentheses" into type definitions with respect to qualifiers such as `const`.

That is, `const std::string &` means:

Apply reference to a type A, which is `const` applied to a type B, which is `std::string`.

However, `const _strref` means:

Apply `const` to a type A, which is `_strref`, which is a reference to `std::string`.

In other words, the non-typedef version gives a reference to a constant string, while the typedef version yields a "constant" reference to a mutable string. Since references themselves cannot be constant or nonconstant, the `const` gets simply dropped.

If you really want to use such typedefs, you'll have to put the `const` into the typedef:

```
typedef const std::string & _cstrref;
```

However, I think reference typedefs (and to a lesser degree, pointer typedefs as well) worsen readability of a program. When I see a function declaration without `&` in front of a parameter, I expect passing by value occurs.