# In C, is it good form to use typedef for a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, typedef

Consider the following C code:

```
typedef char * MYCHAR;
MYCHAR x;
```

My understanding is that the result would be that x is a pointer of type "char".  However, if the declaration of x were to occur far away from the typedef command, a human reader of the code would not immediately know that x is a pointer.  Alternatively, one could use

```
typedef char MYCHAR;
MYCHAR *x;
```

Which is considered to be better form? Is this more than a matter of style?

Comment: It is a matter of taste (and coding rules). Personally, I dislike hiding "pointerness" in `typedef`, so I don't like `typedef char* MYSTRING;` at all...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use pointer typedefs only in situations when the pointer nature of the resultant type is of no significance. For example, pointer typedef is justified when one wants to declare an opaque "handle" type which just happens to be implemented as a pointer, but is not supposed to be usable as a pointer by the user.

```
typedef struct HashTableImpl *HashTable;
/* 'struct HashTableImpl' is (or is supposed to be) an opaque type */
```

In the above example, `HashTable` is a "handle" for a hash table. The user will receive that handle initially from, say, `CreateHashTable` function and pass it to, say, `HashInsert` function and such. The user is not supposed to care (or even know) that `HashTable` is a pointer.

But in cases when the user is supposed to understand that the type is actually a pointer and is usable as a pointer, pointer typedefs are significantly obfuscating the code. I would avoid them. Declaring pointers explicitly makes code more readable.

It is interesting to note that C standard library avoids such pointer typedefs. For example, `FILE` is obviously intended to be used as an opaque type, which means that the library could have defined it as `typedef FILE <some pointer type>` instead of making us to use `FILE *` all the time. But for some reason they decided not to.

Answer (score 12):

If the pointer is never meant to be dereferenced or otherwise manipulated directly -- IOW, you only pass it as an argument to an API -- then it's okay to hide the pointer behind a typedef.

Otherwise, it's better to make the "pointerness" of the type explicit.

Comment: Pointers to incomplete types are perfectly valid as function arguments, and you cannot dereference them either. IOW: You don't *need* to hide them behind silly typedefs, not even in a "secret" API.

Comment: @wildplasser: I think that the point is not that it's good practice to hide a pointer in opaque types (that you just pass around), but that it's bad practice to hide pointers when they have to be treated as such (e.g. the hideous `typedef char * string;`).

Comment: Simple and succinct answer. Might as well add the fact that when creating pointer types, one might need to create `const`-qualified versions of them, for reasons you're surely aware of.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer leaving the `*`, it shows there's a pointer. And your second example should be shortened as `char* x;`, it makes no sense.

Answer (score 4):

I don't particularly like typedef to a pointer, but there is one advantage to it.  It removes confusion and common mistakes when you declare more than one pointer variable in a single declaration.

```
typedef char *PSTR;
...
PSTR str1, str2, str3;
```

is arguably clearer than:

```
char *str1, str2, str3;  // oops
```

Comment: It is a good consequence, but that consequence is a bad reason on its own to typedef :)

Answer (score 3):

I also think this is a matter of style/convention. In Apple's Core Graphics library they frequently  "hide" the pointer and use a convention of appending "Ref" to the end of the type.  So for example, `CGImage *` corresponds to `CGImageRef`. That way you still know it's a pointer reference.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at it is from the perspective of *types*. A type defines the operations that are possible on that type, and the syntax to invokes these operations. From this perspective, MYCHAR is whatever it is. It is the programmers responsibility to know the operations allowed on it. If it is declared like the first example, then it supports the * operator. You can always name the identifier appropriately to clarify it's use.

Other cases where it is useful to declare a type that is a pointer is when the nature of the parameter is opaque to the user (programmer). There may be APIs that want to return a pointer to the user, and expect the user to pass it back to the API at some other point. Like a opaque handle or a cookie, to be used by the API only internally. The user does not care about the nature of the parameter. It would make sense not to muddy the waters or expose its exact nature by exposing the * in the API.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at several existing APIs, it looks as if not putting the pointerness into the type seems better style:

- the already mentionned `FILE *`
- the `MYSQL *` returned by [MySQL's `mysql_real_connect()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-real-connect.html)
- the `MYSQL *` returned by MySQL's [`mysql_store_result()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-store-result.html) and [`mysql_use_result()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-use-result.html)

and probably many others.

Answer (score 0):

For an API it is **not** necessary to hide structure definitions and pointers behind "abstract" typedefs.

```
        /* This is part of the (hypothetical) WDBC- API
        ** It could be found in wdbc_api.h
        ** The struct connection and struct statement ar both incomplete types,
        ** but we are allowed to use pointers to incomplete types, as long as we don't
        ** dereference them.
         */
struct connection *wdbc_connect (char *connection_string);
int wdbc_disconnect (struct connection *con);
int wdbc_prepare (struct connection * con, char *statement);

int main(void)
{
  struct connection *conn;
  struct statement *stmt;
  int rc;

  conn = wdbc_connect( "host='localhost' database='pisbak' username='wild' password='plasser'" );
  stmt = wdbc_prepare (conn, "Select id FROM users where name='wild'" );

  rc = wdbc_disconnect (conn);

  return 0;
}
```

The above fragment compiles fine. (but it fails to link, obviously)

Answer (score 0):

> Is this more than a matter of style?

Yes. For instance, this:

```
typedef int *ip;
const ip p;
```

is not the same as:

```
const int *p; // p is non-const pointer to const int
```

It is the same as:

```
int * const p; // p is constant pointer to non-const int
```

Read about const weirdness with typedef here [typedef pointer const weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8504411/6699433)