# C dynamic array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to write a simple implementation of dynamic arrays of strings in C. Here's my code (**minus the includes and main function etc ...**):

```
typedef char* string;

typedef struct {

    string* list;
    size_t size;
    size_t used;

} list;

void initList(list* l, size_t initSize) {

    l->list = malloc(initSize * sizeof(string));
    l->used = 0;
    l->size = initSize;

}

void insertList(list* l, string elem) {

    if (l->used == l->size) {
        l->size *= 2;
        l->list = realloc(l->list, l->size * sizeof(string));
    }
    l->list[l->used++] = elem;

}
```

My code seems to work as I expect, I'm asking my question because I read that you should use `char[]` instead of `char*`.

I read that using `typedef char* string` declares the string in read-only memory, so trying to modify it causes undefined behaviour.

If so, using the GCC C compiler I don't receive any errors or warnings and the code seems to work when compiled.

The functions for creating and growing the dynamic array where taken from another question on StackOverflow, the original question created a dynamic array of integers.

I'm just curious as to if my code is good/bad practice.

Comment: `char[]` declares an *array* of char. `char*` is a *pointer* to a char. `typedef char* string` creates a new type called `string`, which is a pointer to a char (no difference)

Comment: String literals are read-only. If `char *string` points to a string literal, it is undefined behavior to attempt to modify the string through the pointer. But `string` may also point to an element of a null-terminated array of `char`s allocated at runtime. Then it is fine to modify the string through the pointer.

Comment: `typedef char* string` is from [CS50](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cs50); many find it not at all useful to represent strings in this way. It is generally considered bad practice to typedef pointers in the first place, which tends to lead to confusion and errors. Doing this with strings hides what is really happening from the programmer. Why not use null-terminated arrays, which is what strings are, and use pointers to `char` when needed?

Comment: It is generally a *bad idea* to `typedef` pointers. Why? You are hiding one (or more) levels of indirection obfuscating the actual `type` involved. See [**In C, is it good form to use typedef for a pointer?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135033/in-c-is-it-good-form-to-use-typedef-for-a-pointer). This can lead to debugging headaches, dereference errors, and make the code much less readable for someone trying to maintain the code, or help answer questions to help you, etc. The answer by @AnT referenced above covers both when a typedef to a pointer is appropriate as well as not.

Comment: `I read that using typedef char* string declares the string in read-only memory, so trying to modify it causes undefined behaviour.` - WRONG ASSUMPTION.

Answer (score 0):

> I read that using typedef char* string declares the string in read-only memory, so trying to modify it causes undefined behaviour.

Well, that's nonsense. You might confuse this with something like

```
char *foo = "foo";
```

In that case, although `foo` is a mutable pointer to a mutable set of characters, the characters it points to are NOT mutable. This is because a "string literal" in C always lives in non-mutable memory. It doesn't help that `foo` isn't `const` here. A good compiler will warn you, though -- you should only assign string literals to `const char *`.

If you want a mutable string, initialize a `char[]` from it, this way it's not a pointer and the compiler knows to place it in mutable memory. But this really only concerns literals.

So there's nothing wrong with using `char *` as your `string` type. In fact, that's what C does implicitly for string literals. I'd still have a little objection: Seasoned C-programmers will know about `char *` et al and they will expect that "plain" strings are `char *` (or `const char *`). If you name something `string`, it should somehow provide more than that. If it doesn't, just don't confuse people and go by `char *`.

Comment: Hmmm. C does not have a `string` type.

Comment: @DavidBowling it has a notion of strings and it has string literals.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by, "... using `char *` as your `string` type. In fact, that's what c does."

Comment: "its pointer is taken" makes no sense.  And the properties of memory belong to that memory, not to any pointers to it.

Comment: You can't assign to an array. I expect you meant "initialise a `char[]` with a string literal". (You can assign a string literal to a `const char *`. Confusing assignment with definition is not a good path to learning C, so it is useful to be clear about what you mean.)

Comment: @rici um yes, this should be initialise, i'll edit that

Comment: String literals are not implicitly `char *`; they are [arrays of static storage duration](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p6).

Comment: @DavidBowling they evaluate to `char *` and I really won't edit the question in a way the asker won't understand any more.

Comment: It is confusing to say that C implicitly uses `char *` for string literals; it does not, it uses arrays as mentioned in my previous comment. Beginners often misunderstand this, thinking that string literals are pointers to `const char`; they are not. Beginners often misunderstand that arrays are pointers; they are not, implicitly or otherwise.