# Initialize recursive struct type in C properly

Tags: c, recursion, struct

I am new to C programming and I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct _date {
    char d[10], t[5], s[3];
    struct _date *next;
} *date;
```

How can I properly create an instance of this?

My solution:

```
date neuerTermin(char *d, char *t, char *s, date cal) {
    struct _date d = {*d, *t, *s, NULL};
    date d_ptr = malloc(sizeof *d);
    cal->next = d_ptr;

    return d;
}
```

But I get an error: `warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast`

Comment: Hint: What is the error you get if you remove the `!= 0` check?

Comment: if your typedef were a pointer it would probably be what you want.

Comment: @BrianCain thanks that solved the problem. This pointer stuff is confusing.

Comment: Now how can initialize a termin?

Comment: *"This pointer stuff is confusing.*" -- and it will get even more so if you `typedef` pointers effectively hiding the true level of indirection behind a `typedef`. Initialization only applies to static declarations (e.g. `struct _date d1 = { .d = "somestr", .t = "foo", .s = "to" }`, all omitted members are initialized to all zero). Since your `date` typedef is a pointer, you cannot do `date d1 = { initializer }`, instead you must do `date d1 = malloc (sizeof *d1);` and then use assignment or `memcpy` to fill the values (after validating your allocation succeeded)

Comment: @user3621741  It is totally unclear what you are trying to do. For example where are the variables date and d_ptr declared? why is not the parameter cal used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _date {
    char d[11], t[6], s[4]; // +1 to size for null-terminator ('\0')
    struct _date *next;
} *date;


int main() {
    struct _date a = { "15.07.2017", "16:00", "Foo", NULL };
    date a_ptr = &a;

    printf("Description: %s\nDate: %s\nTime: %s\n", a_ptr->s, a_ptr->d, a_ptr->t);
    return 0;
}
```

The brace-enclosed, comma-separated list in the example above is the [struct initializer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization).

---

To respond to the edits of your question, if you wish to dynamically allocate `struct _date` instances and initialize them in a function, then use [`malloc`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm) as follows:

```
date neuerTermin(const char* d, const char* t, const char* s) {
    date cal = (date)malloc(sizeof(struct _date));

    strncpy(cal->d, d, 10);
    strncpy(cal->t, t, 5);
    strncpy(cal->s, s, 3);
    cal->next = NULL;

    return cal;
}
```

In this case you have to fill the memory block pointed by `cal` member-by-member. Sample usage:

```
date root = neuerTermin("15.07.2017", "16:00", "Foo");
root->next = neuerTermin("27.07.2017", "10:00", "Bar");
root->next->next = neuerTermin("01.08.2017", "12:30", "Baz");
```

**Important:** if you used `malloc` to allocate memory, you have to deallocate it too with using [`free`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_free.htm) when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I wanted to do ^^.
I have tried to but this into a function:

    `date neuerTermin(char *d, char *t, char *s, date cal) {
        struct _date d = {*d, *t, *s, NULL};
        date = malloc(sizeof *d_ptr);
        
        cal->next = d_ptr;
        
        return d;
    }`

But I get an error: `warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast`

Comment: Does strncpy need the extra size for null-terminator?
And if I assign the next date in the function like this `(calParameter->next = cal;)`, I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: @user3621741, the `strncpy` automatically adds the `'\0'` to the destination therefore it must be long enough to receive the null-terminator too. I recommend to you to ask another question if you still have issues. Edit the current one (its title too) to be understandable, mark the good answers as useful and accept the one you think that answered your current question. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page if you are not sure.

Answer (score 2):

While Akira has a very good answer for you (I voted for it), I would caution you about *typedeffing pointers*. Why? As your projects grow, when you start hiding levels of indirection behind a `typedef`, the level of confusion and potential for error grows.

If you need a pointer of a typedeffed type, declare an instance of one, but keep your typedefs to types so an not to mask levels of indirection.

You can do the same thing without hiding the level of indirection as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _date {
    char d[11], t[6], s[4]; // +1 for '\0'
    struct _date *next;
} date;


int main() {
    date a = { "15.07.2017", "16:00", "Foo", NULL };
    date *a_ptr = &a;

    printf("Description: %s\nDate: %s\nTime: %s\n", a_ptr->s, a_ptr->d, a_ptr->t);
    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
PS> .\bin\structtypedef.exe
Description: Foo
Date: 15.07.2017
Time: 16:00
```

Typedeffing pointers is now wrong, it just creates pitfalls. See: [**In C, is it good form to use typedef for a pointer?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135033/in-c-is-it-good-form-to-use-typedef-for-a-pointer).

Comment: yes, I had done this before. But I needed to do this because in already existing code (which can't be changed) there is this: `date cal = 0;` and it works only with pointers.

Comment: That makes sense. There are just so many people trying to make things hard on themselves (while actually thinking they are making things easier). Good luck with your coding.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Do you know whats the problem in the code above (I have edited the question)?

Comment: Well `date = malloc(sizeof *d_ptr);` this is a problem. Maybe `date mydate = malloc(sizeof *d_ptr);` Recall `date` is an alias to `struct _date*` it is not an instance of a pointer itself. You need to declare a variable of `date` type, e.g. `date mydate = ...`. You may have other problems as well, but no way to tell without a [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Nice explanation of why don't hide a pointer into a `typedef`.