# convert array to binary tree with recursive strategy

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, binary-tree

I need to create a binary tree starting from vector containing some zeros where a zero represents a node that doesn't exists. for example if I got:

int a[] = {10,4,7,2,3,-1,8,9,-1,2,4,5};

I would like my output like this:

```
         10
        /   \
       4     7
      / \     \
     2   3     8
    /   / \   /
   9   2   4 5
```

my struct:

```
  typedef struct node {
   int n;
   struct node * dx;
   struct node * sx;
  } *Bit_node;
```

method to build one node:

```
  Bit_node bit_new(int n) {
    Bit_node new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node -> n = n;
    return new_node;
  }
```

method to build the whole tree:

```
  Bit_node bit_arr2tree(int a[], int size, int i) {
  if (i>= size) {
      return NULL;
  }
  if(a[i] != -1) {
   Bit_node new_node = bit_new(a[i]);
   new_node -> sx = bit_arr2tree(a, size, i*2 +1);
   new_node -> dx = bit_arr2tree(a, size, i*2 +2);
  }
  
  return new_node;
}
```

But with my implementation my tree is built not considering the "holes". Is there a way to considering them , keeping the recursive strategy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `int a[] = {10,4,7,2,3,-1,8,9,-1,2,4,5};` shouldn't produce the tree you expect, with 5 as the left child of 8. Since 8 is at index 6, its left child would be at index `6 * 2 + 1 == 13`. So your input should probably be `int a[] = {10,4,7,2,3,-1,8,9,-1,2,4,-1,-1,5};`, with two extra -1s towards the end of the array to push 5 to the correct index.

Your implementation can't work because in the pattern:

```c
{
    Bit_node new_node = malloc(...)
}
return new_node;
```

`new_node` is being accessed when not in scope. If you encounter a -1, you want to return NULL just like you're doing if you go out of bounds on the array. Returning NULL says "there is no child here", which is exactly what you want to communicate to a parent frame so that it sets the missing child to NULL.

The fix should be pretty straightforward:

```c
Bit_node bit_arr2tree(int a[], int size, int i) {
    if (i>= size || a[i] < 0) {
    //           ^^^^^^^^^^^
        return NULL;
    }

    Bit_node new_node = bit_new(a[i]);
    new_node->sx = bit_arr2tree(a, size, i * 2 + 1);
    new_node->dx = bit_arr2tree(a, size, i * 2 + 2);
    return new_node;
}
```

As an aside, I'd caution [against typedeffing away pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135033/in-c-is-it-good-form-to-use-typedef-for-a-pointer). This makes the code less readable and hides information.

Here's a runnable proof of concept:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
};

struct Node *arr2tree(int arr_len, int *arr, int i) {
    if (i >= arr_len || arr[i] < 0) {
        return NULL;
    }

    struct Node *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    node->data = arr[i];
    node->left = arr2tree(arr_len, arr, i * 2 + 1);
    node->right = arr2tree(arr_len, arr, i * 2 + 2);
    return node;
}

void print_tree(struct Node *root, int depth) {
    if (root) {
        print_tree(root->right, depth + 4);

        for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
            printf(" ");
        }

        printf("%d\n", root->data);
        print_tree(root->left, depth + 4);
    }
}

void free_tree(struct Node *root) {
    if (root) {
        free_tree(root->left);
        free_tree(root->right);
        free(root);
    }
}

int main() {
    int a[] = {10,4,7,2,3,-1,8,9,-1,2,4,-1,-1,5};
    struct Node *root = arr2tree(sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]), a, 0);
    print_tree(root, 0);
    free_tree(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
        8
            5
    7
10
            4
        3
            2
    4
        2
            9
```

Comment: I don't understand why, by putting the or condition, doesn't stop the recursion on the first -1 value  :(

Comment: It **does** stop the recursion at the first -1 value but only for that branch of the recursion. Each frame spawns two calls -- if one returns NULL early because that child doesn't exist (i.e. is -1 or out of bounds of the array), the other one may well keep recursing. You might want to use a debugger and try a simpler tree with 3-4 nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the input data structure does not guarantee the relationship between parent and children is `i*2+1` and `i*2+2`, a recursive solution is not really called for. The input sequence represents a breadth-first order, so it would be more natural to build the tree in breadth-first order.

As a side note: the function `bit_new` should also initialise the `sx` and `dx` members: you don't want to leave those with undefined values.

Here is how you could write your algorithm:

```
Bit_node bit_new(int n) {
    Bit_node new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node -> n = n;
    new_node -> sx = NULL;
    new_node -> dx = NULL;
    return new_node;
}   


Bit_node bit_arr2tree(int a[], int size) {
    if (size == 0) {
        return NULL;
    }
    // Create a temporary array to store the node pointers
    Bit_node nodes[size];
    // Create the nodes
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        nodes[i] = a[i] == -1 ? NULL : bit_new(a[i]);
    }
    // To link the nodes, use two indexes: parent and child
    for (int child = 1, parent = 0; child < size; child += 2, parent++) {
        // Here we "skip the gaps": a parent cannot be NULL:
        while (nodes[parent] == NULL) {
            parent++;
        }
        nodes[parent] -> sx = nodes[child];
        if (child + 1 < size) {
            nodes[parent] -> dx = nodes[child + 1];
        }
    }
    return nodes[0];
}
```