# How to correctly deallocate structure from memory

Tags: c, malloc, binary-tree

I have a dynamic data structure which looks like this:

```
struct tree_node {
    int y;
    int x;
    struct tree_node *left;
    struct tree_node *right;
    struct tree_node *parent;
};
```

The structure is a node of a binary tree, with the addition that each node also points to its parent. Now, using the classical method of adding nodes to the binary tree using `malloc()` I can populate the binary tree easily. However, I am having trouble deallocating the binary tree from memory.

Usually, to remove nodes from the binary tree you perform a post-order traversal and then free each node like this:

```
void deleteTree(struct tree_node* node)
{
    if (node == NULL) return;

    deleteTree(node->left);
    deleteTree(node->right);

    printf("Deleting node with values [%d][%d]\n", node->y , node-> x);

    free(node -> left);
    free(node -> right);
    free(node -> parent);
    free(node);
    printf("\nNode deleted");
}
```

However, when I run the above function it does not deallocate the binary tree from memory. When I run the function, it deallocates one leaf and then when it tries to delete the next node it gets stuck in an endless loop and my computer either crashes or the program exits with a non-descriptive error.

The output in the terminal is the following:

```
Deleting node with values [11][4]
Node deleted
Deleting node with values [7739840][0]
```

So the terminal shows that it deletes the first leaf, and then it tries to fetch the values from the next node but it cannot (which is why it displays 7739840). Then it gets stuck in an endless loop since it does not print "Node deleted".

How can I correctly deallocate the memory? Does it have to do with the way my node is built?

Comment: Please [edit] and show a [mcve].

Comment: Just from my gut, I'd say you are trying to access a member of a freed structure.

Comment: Fyi, the output on my compiler tells me there is no `next_1` or `next_2` members of `struct tree_node`, when `deleteTree(node->next_1);` and `deleteTree(node->next_2);` are encountered. And judging by your stated structure definition, that's correct. So either the posted structure isn't real, or the posted code isn't (or both?). One thing with near-certainty, however: `free(node -> parent);` is *wrong*. the parent will be deleted in a parental recursion. In fact, so will `left` and `right` if you pass those to `deleteTree` rather than the fictitious `next_` and `next_2`.

Comment: `struct treenode` does not have `next_1` and `next_2` fields.

Comment: The primary issue I see right now is, that you are calling `free(node->left)` etc, meaning you deallocate the left/right/parent nodes from memory. Once you go back to the parent object, its memory has already been deallocated, meaning that you are now accessing uninitialized memory.

Comment: Recursive deletion basically works like this, assuming `root` is the pointer to the root node: 1. delete `root->left`, 2. delete `root->right`, 3. delete `root`. Just don't do anything with the parent node. Probaby removing all frees except `free(node)` will do the job, but I didn't check thoroughly because you didn't provide a [mcve]

Comment: @WhozCraig My code had  conflicting struct members, but I changed it. The inconsistency was a mistake on my part.

Comment: Pay close attention to Refugnic's comment: The only `free` call in that function should be `free(node);`. the entire function should be four lines long. 1. leave if `node` is null. Otherwise 2. `deleteTree(node->left);`, then 3. `deleteTree(node->right)`, and finally 4. `free(node);` That's it.

Comment: Tip: After `free()` set the pointer to `(struct tree_node *)0xDEADBEEFDEADBEEF;` or `NULL` and you will quickly find any double free or use after free case. Your code will crash instead of loop forever.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way of deallocating all the nodes from your tree structure looks like this:

```c
void deleteTree(struct tree_node* node)
{
    if (node == NULL) return;

    deleteTree(node->left);
    deleteTree(node->right);

    free(node);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You're deallocating nodes multiple times.

When you delete a given node, after `deleteTree(node->left)` is called the left node has already been freed, so it doesn't need to be freed again.  So remove `free(node->left)`.

The *current* node has also been freed because `free(node->parent)` was called in that function, so any further reads of `node` access freed memory.  So remove `free(node->parent)`.

And similarly to the call to `deleteTree(node->left)`, calling `deleteTree(node->right)` already frees the right node, so remove the call to `free(node->right)`.

So now you're left with:

```
void deleteTree(struct tree_node* node)
{
    if (node == NULL) return;

    deleteTree(node->left);
    deleteTree(node->right);

    printf("Deleting node with values [%d][%d]\n", node->y , node-> x);

    free(node);
    printf("\nNode deleted");
}
```

In short, each node is responsible for cleaning itself up.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are freeing the same node multiple times.

To delete a binary search tree you have to do something like this.

```
void bst_destroy(BSTNode node) {
    if (node == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    bst_destroy(node->left);
    bst_destroy(node->right);

    free(node);
}
```

Basically to delete a binary search tree you have to delete the leaves of the tree one by one so you don't end up deleting parent nodes you might have to visit again (which you will have to do if you are using recursion).

Comment: BTW: don't hide pointers behind typedefs, it only causes confusion. It should be `struct BSTNode *node` without typefefs whatsoever. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135033/in-c-is-it-good-form-to-use-typedef-for-a-pointer