# Is it possible to define a var to be a pointer to const when the type is defined as a pointer to a struct?

Tags: c, pointers, constants, declaration, typedef

Let's say `test_t` is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct test_t { 
    void *unused; 
} *(test_t)
```

Is it possible define a variable to be a pointer to const without modifying the definition of `test_t`?

`const test_t var` would be a const pointer to `struct test_t`, right?

I have this problem since sonarqube recommends to "Make the type of this variable a pointer-to-const" but I can't change the definition since it is used in many other places where the variable should be a pointer to `struct test_t`.

Comment: Note that [it's usually a really bad idea to hide pointers behind a `typedef`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135033/in-c-is-it-good-form-to-use-typedef-for-a-pointer).

Comment: I understood that it is used to emulate type safety in C? It is in my project which I can't control.

Comment: If you must hide pointers behind a typedef, you would need to use `const struct test_t *` (or `struct test_t const *`) for the type of the variable, or typedef another type: `typedef const struct test_t *test_t_const;`.

Comment: @lifang You probably need to write a bug report on the `typedef`, given the answers posted here.  Given that a human brain can only keep track of a handful of things at any one time, why on Earth would some unthinking "architect" create typedefs that force every programmer working on a project to waste a significant bit of brain power on keeping track of "this is *really* a *pointer*"?!? That's just begging for needless bugs to be introduced. Just read all the bugs under the `cs50` tag that spring from the horrendous benighted  `typedef char *string` abomination.

Comment: (cont) [A human brain can track 3-7 things at any one time](https://www.google.com/search?q=a+human+brain+can+only+keep+track+of+a+handful+of+things).  Forcing developers to waste one of those things on "this is really a pointer" is just thoughtless.

Answer (score 7):

Do not hide pointers behind typedefs. It is a very bad practice and in your case it makes impossible to declare such variable.

```
typedef struct test_t { 
    void *unused; 
} test_t;

const test_t *var;
```

Answer (score 4):

This typedef declaration

```
typedef struct test_t { 
    void *unused; 
} *(test_t);
```

declares the name `test_t` as an alias for the type `struct test_t *`.

So this declaration

```
const test_t var;
```

that may be equivalently written like

```
test_t const var;
```

actually denotes the following declaration

```
struct test_t * const var;
```

That is it declares the variable `var` as a constant pointer not as a pointer to a constant object of the type `struct test_t`.

If you want to declare the variable `var`  as a pointer to constant data then you have to write

```
const struct test_t *var;
```

If you want to declare a constant pointer to constant data then you have to write

```
const struct test_t * const var;
```

However if you want to declare a constant pointer then you need to initialize it in its declaration.

Otherwise you could rewrite the typedef declaration the following way

```
typedef struct test_t { 
    void *unused; 
} test_t;
```

and then write

```
const test_t *var;
```

In this case the name `test_t` is an alias for the type specifier `struct test_t` and the qualifier `const` produces the type specifier `const struct test_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to do without modifications. You just need to *copy-paste* the entire `typedef` and *then* change *that*, e.g.

```
typedef const struct { 
    void *unused; 
} *const_test_t;
```

Of course you couldn't pass this to anything that requires pointer to non-const `test_t` and such.

However if the declaration *indeed* uses `struct test_t {...}` then do note that it *also* declares the struct tag `test_t`, which you can use too. So, instead of

```
const test_t var:
```

you would use the struct tag with the struct keyword:

```
const struct test_t *ptr;
```

But if the struct was declared anonymously i.e. `typedef const struct { } *test_t;` then copying is the only option.

The real fix is (as everyone says here) to *not* use a typedef to hide pointers wherever they shouldn't be.

Comment: Without changing the typedef he wanted

Comment: @0___________ you're mistaken, I've not changed the typedef. I created another one.