# Building a binary tree in C language

Tags: c, binary-tree

so, I am trying to build a binary tree in C language, I am scanning first of all an integer that represents the number of the nodes in the tree, then I scan the elements and to put them in the tree such that in the node 'i' its left node is the element 2i+1 that was scanned, and in its right node the element 2i+2 that was scanned.
('i' repersents the "index" of the scanned elements).
I can't  use arrays or a linked list, and I can't add a field in the structure of the tree that contains its index.

this is what I did:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct Node *NodePtr;
typedef struct {
    int val;
    NodePtr left;
    NodePtr right;
}Node;


void insert_element(NodePtr tree,int element);


int main(void)
{
    int n, i, element;
    printf("Enter number of elements: \n");
    if(scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
    {
        printf("Input Error!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Enter elements: \n");
   
    return 0;
}

void insert_element(NodePtr tree,int element)
{
    
}
```

in the function "insert_element" I don't even know where to start

Comment: Draw a tree on a piece of paper. Next to every node on your tree, write down, what values the struct properties contain. That should give you a good visualisation

Comment: I did that but I can't get the notion of what should I do

Comment: Start with a small example tree.  Then consider adding a new element (trying different values), and see what the resulting tree should look like.  Then figure out how to transform the old tree into the new tree.

Comment: You can also talk to yourself or find another person and try to explain that person, what happens. Often talking about the problem helps in conceptualizing.  Go through the process of adding an element to the tree step by step. That's how you come up with algorithms.

Comment: SO is not a tutoring service, we can't walk you through programming this. There's lots of example code on the Internet and in other SO questions.

Comment: I'd start by drawing a tree with 7 nodes. Write the index numbers in the nodes. Then convert the index numbers to binary. After that's finished you should notice that you'll be much better of by adding 1 to each index. So start over an write the index plus 1 in each node. Convert those to binary. Then take a picture and add the picture to your question.

Comment: Hint: don't hide pointers behind typedefs, it only adds confusion. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135033/in-c-is-it-good-form-to-use-typedef-for-a-pointer