issue erasing elements in a vector using C
I wanted to go "back to the basics" and try writing a C vector implementation.
It is using void* to store the data and i try to mimic the C++ counter part a little bit.
I am having difficulty erasing elements. precisely the size of the vector does not seem to match of whats expected after erasing multiple elements.
Here is the implementation of the erase function:
typedef void* vector_iterator;

vector_iterator vector_begin(vector* vec) {
    return vec->data;
}

vector_iterator vector_end(vector* vec) {
    return ((unsigned char*)vec->data) + ((vec->element_size * (vec->size+1))); // "past the last element"
}

void vector_erase(vector* vec, vector_iterator iterator) {
    assert(iterator >= vector_begin(vec));
    assert(iterator < vector_end(vec));
    assert(((uintptr_t)iterator - (uintptr_t)vector_begin(vec)) % vec->element_size == 0);
    unsigned char* dest = (unsigned char*)iterator;
    unsigned char* src = dest + vec->element_size; // src is the element erased element + 1, since we want to pull all objects forward
    size_t bytes_to_copy= (unsigned char*)vector_end(vec) - (unsigned char*)src - vec->element_size;
    memcpy(dest, src, bytes_to_copy); // copy all elements from (iterator +1) forward
    vec->size--;
}

vector_iterator vector_iterator_offset(vector_iterator iterator,vector* vec, ptrdiff_t offset) {
    return (unsigned char*)iterator + (vec->element_size * offset);
}


The usage of erasing is used like this.
vector_erase(vec, vector_iterator_offset(vector_begin(vec),vec,2)); // erase the second element

When I erase 3 elements, the reported size of the vector is correct, but my loop prints size+1 elements.
    vector* vec = vector_create_capacity(sizeof(char), 10);
    //test for push back
    for(char i = 'A'; i < 'A'+10; ++i) {
        vector_push_back(vec, &i);
    }
    
    //...//
    
    fprintf(stdout, "Size: %zu\n",vector_size(vec));
    fflush(stdout);

    vector_erase(vec, vector_iterator_offset(vector_begin(vec),vec,2)); // erase 'C'
    fprintf(stdout, "Size: %zu\n",vector_size(vec));
    fflush(stdout);

    vector_erase(vec, vector_iterator_offset(vector_begin(vec),vec,2)); // erase 'D'
    fprintf(stdout, "Size: %zu\n",vector_size(vec));
    fflush(stdout);

    vector_erase(vec, vector_iterator_offset(vector_begin(vec),vec,2)); // erase 'E'
    fprintf(stdout, "Size: %zu\n",vector_size(vec));
    fflush(stdout);
    
    it = vector_begin(vec);
    for(;it != vector_end(vec); (it = vector_iterator_offset(it, vec, 1))) {
        
        char data = *(char*)it;
        fprintf(stdout,"%c\n", data);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    fprintf(stdout,"%zu",vector_size(vec));
    fflush(stdout);
    //8 printed letters instead of 7 with double 'J'?
    vector_destroy(vec);

The output at the end is
A
B
F
G
H
I
J
J

Godbolt demo, because the code is very long
is my vector_end(vec) incorrect or is the erasing incorrect?

Note: (slightly OT) memcpy of overlapping memory regions can produce undefined behavior. Use memmove instead.

You do not need brackets on the 3rd for expression. Just for (it = begin; it != end; it = vector_iterator_offset()) . -fanalyzer complains about missing NULL checks.

In the godbolt you posted , size_to_end and bytes_to_copy are equal (?)

Unrelated to your question, there are other ways to implement this nowadays by cooking up a template-like macro solution based on types, using _Generic and typeof and probably X-macros. Pretty evil-looking code to the point where I wouldn't really recommend it, but type safe and you get the sizes sorted by the compiler.

Unrealed, style, subjective: don't hide pointerness behind a typedef -- see, eg, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135033/in-c-is-it-good-form-to-use-typedef-for-a-pointer


 // "past the last element"


But size + 1 points to the byte past the next element after the last. So it's not "past the last element", it is "the byte after one plus last element".
When you are at the vec->data + vec->element_size * vec->size you already are pointing at the byte past the last element. No +1, the size is already the count of elements in the vector, and arrays index from 0.

is my vector_end(vec) incorrect or is the erasing incorrect?

Yes, vector_end is confusing. Just:
vector_iterator vector_end(vector* vec) {
    return ((char *)vec->data) + vec->element_size * vec->size; // "past the last element"
}

And then naturally you copy the range between end and start.
 size_t bytes_to_copy = (unsigned char*)vector_end(vec) - (unsigned char*)src;

My godbolt link https://godbolt.org/z/z5TvWzM7T .

Subjective cosmetics:

amazing code
typedef pointers are still a red flag for me.

I would do typedef struct { vector *parent; void *pos; } vector_iterator instead of passing two parameters each time.
or at least typedef struct { void *pos; } vector_iterator; so that I get rudimentary type checking
but with void * you get nice != comparison, so I understand it's nice to have


if you do not plan to dereference it, just use char * to represent byte, no need to type unsigned.
so many ( ), they are not needed in some places
#include "assert.h" -> #include <assert.h>
does vector_create_capacity needs to allocate memory twice and for vector itself? It could just return itself by value vector vector_create_capacity(...).
some places are missing NULL allocation error checks, see gcc -fanalyzer complaining
overall great code

Also, I have lately more and more fun with STC library, you can see its vector implementation here https://github.com/stclib/STC/blob/master/docs/vec_api.md .

You beat me with one minute so I'll just scrap my answer :)  +1

the vector is hidden as a opaque struct which is why I allocate the vector and the data.
Thanks for the help. It's insane how much C++ takes away from you compared to C.
When I apply the changes to vector_erase and vector_end I receive the same issue, but with a double I instead. And if I remember correctly only unsigend char is a standard way to represent raw bytes. But I could be wrong.

@Raildex That's correct, you have to use a character type for it. Which creates another problem: during allocation of new types you have to make sure to "touch" that new memory area using a write access of the intended type, not character type. Because if you write access it using character type and later try to access it with the intended type, you get strict aliasing violation - undefined behavior.

but with a double I instead the godbolt link there prints one I. I do not think I changed anything else...

@Lundin I am only ever dereferencing objects at their respective adresses, am I no? Why would a different T not work?

@Raildex Because of the C type system, each address has an "effective type" which is the formal name for what type the compiler thinks is stored there. If you access it through a different type, you invoke undefined behavior. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule
