# invalid conversion from ‘const BYTE* {aka const unsigned char*}’ to ‘BYTE_PTR {aka unsigned char*}’

Tags: c++, casting, typedef

I don't know why g++ compiler gives me error when compiling this code:

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
typedef BYTE* BYTE_PTR;

const BYTE myByte[] = {0x00, 0xFF};
const BYTE_PTR myByte_ptr = myByte;
```

compiler gives me this error:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘const BYTE* {aka const unsigned char*}’ to ‘BYTE_PTR {aka unsigned char*}’ [-fpermissive]
```

But this code is OK

```
const BYTE myByte[] = {0x00, 0xFF};
const unsigned char* myByte_ptr = myByte;
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504411/typedef-pointer-const-weirdness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate of [typedef pointer const weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504411/typedef-pointer-const-weirdness)

And in short:
`const BYTE_PTR` is actually `unsigned char* const`, but not `const unsigned char*`.

That's why the compiler complains.