# get rid of `deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’` warnings in GCC using typedefs?

Tags: c++, typedef

I'm working on updating a very large codebase to be able to use gcc4.3 and ran into this issue. The question has been asked several times, however I think my situation is a little unique and Haven't been able to get a good explanation out of it.

The error I get is

> error: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'realchar {aka char*}'

realchar refers to a typedef I have:

```cpp
typedef char*   realchar;

public:
ClassNameIsMe(const realchar name="UsyncBndLNQueue");
```

changing realChar to be simply char* removes the warning. however shouldn't that be equivalent since it is a typedef pointing to char*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [typedef pointer const weirdness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504411/typedef-pointer-const-weirdness)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `const realchar name` is const pointer to char, i.e  it is equivalent to:

```
char * name const
```

instead of pointer to const char, which would be equivalent to:

```
const char * name
```

So the warning is valid.

---

See details here:

- [Q: typedef pointer const weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504411/typedef-pointer-const-weirdness)
- [Q: Is typedef'ing a pointer type considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781932/is-typedefing-a-pointer-type-considered-bad-practice)